# xcodebuild issue after upgrading to Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line-interface, fastlane

After upgrading to Xcode 12.5 (upgraded from the App Store), some CLI tools like `xcodebuild` and `codesign_allocate` are failing immediately, saying:

`Executable requires at least macOS 11.0, but is being run on macOS 10.16, and so is exiting.`

Even though these are failing, xcode-select works, and the location is set - running `xcode-select -p` outputs `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`. Everything seems to be installed, which `xcode-select --install` indicates. I've tried installing the CLI [from source](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/%60), and putting the bin directory in `PATH` seems to work ok, but this doesn't include `xcodebuild`. However if I don't do manually install those cli tools, I still end up getting prompted to install the cli tools, and after they are "installed", I continue to get the prompt.

Everything within the Xcode IDE works fine, and I've tried reinstalling Xcode multiple times. I'm on the latest version of Big Sur (version 11.3), and this computer has never even had a version of macOS lower than that. Everything was working fine before this upgrade.

Comment: Check your project settings, especially build variables, if you see any references to macOS versions and deployment.

Comment: I also have this issue, using xcodbuild on the command line, without any arguments and it comes out with "Executable requires at least macOS 11.0, but is being run on macOS 10.16, and so is exiting"

Comment: This is the current solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-830184757

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was that I had set `export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1` in my `.bashrc`. This caused the command `sw_vers` to return ProductVersion 10.16, regardless of the actual version of macOS installed. Presumably Xcode version 12.5 started doing some check involving the os version before running binaries.

My solution was to just make sure that environment variable was set to false with `export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0` in my `.bashrc`. Just not setting `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT` also works. To ensure that you have things are working, make sure that running `sw_vers` shows the `ProductVersion` that you expect, which should be >11.